# Is it possible to create NSLayoutContraints for a view created in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, autolayout

I'm learning webdev with meteor and I'd like to use Google Webfonts for my web app.

In a test app, I have a UIImageView that I placed randomly in the ViewController's view via IB.  Then in the code, I tried to apply some constraints, which had no effect.

If I programmatically create the UIImageView within viewDidLoad and then apply the constraints, then it works.

I have a guess that IB is generating some constraints that are causing my own constraints not to take.  Is there any way to put a view within IB and then put the constraints via code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I just found the answer:  I just had to call:

```
[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
```

within viewDidLoad.